# Bootstrap accordion not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to make a collapse accordion to work, but when i click the links nothing happens, the other items are not expanding and the first is not collapsing. The body is split in 3 columns (1-10-1) and the accordion is placed in the middle. I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 and jquery 3.2.1. Is this happening due to how my tags are laid, or is something to do with jquery?

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="container">

        <div  class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">

                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
                                    Panel 1
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Text for 1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                                    Panel 2
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Text for 2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

        </div>

    </div> <!-- Body -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like its working just fine

Comment: your code works fine
https://jsbin.com/bodubuwoho/edit?html,output

Comment: Add jQuery lib at first.

Comment: Indeed in jsbin works fine. I'm trying on both safari and chrome and does not work. What else can i try?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna you are a lifesaver. Didn't know that! Thanks

Comment: Happy to hear. I'll put my answer so that you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add jQuery lib before `bootstrap.js`. Because bootstrap internally uses jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="container">

        <div  class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">

                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
                                    Panel 1
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Text for 1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                                    Panel 2
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Text for 2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

        </div>

    </div> <!-- Body -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I declare jQuery before use boostrap js library but the accordion still not working.